# A better approach to store, write, and read a big dataset of meteorological data

Tags: mongodb, hdf5, netcdf, bigdata

I am looking a better to store, write and read meteorological data (about 30 GB in raw text format).

Currently I am using NetCDF file format to store weather records. In this NetCDF file, I have 3 dimensions: `time`, `climate variables`, `locations`. But the dimension order is the key constrain for my tasks (see below).

The first task is to update weather records every day for about 3000 weather stations. Dimension order `(time, var, name)` provides the best performance for writing as the new data will be added at the end of NetCDF file.

The second task is to read all daily weather record for a station to preform analyzing. Dimension order `(name, var, time)` provides the best performance for reading as all records of one site are stored together.

The two tasks have the conflict designs of NetCDF file (best performance in one task, but the worst performance in another task).

My questions is whether there are alternative methods/software/data format to store, write and read my datasets to provide best performance of my two tasks? As I have to repeat the two steps everyday and data analyzing is time consuming, I need to find a best way to minimize I/O.

Thanks for any suggestions. Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is: are you using compression? That will reduce I/O by a huge amount.

Comment: 3000 stations does not sound like too much, if You order data properly. How do You define Your data, all meteorological variables as separate NetCDF variables or everything in one variable? I would try the latter version, so that each time adding new data could be done by adding one single array. Also check that You have newest netcdf+hdf libraries. I personally don't think compression has much benefit for Your case, because when adding data You should uncompress existing data first, adding data and compressing again

Comment: @kakk11. I agree with you. My dataset is not a very big and compression will reduce performance. My difficult is reading and writing require two opposite data structure for better performance, like I  asked in my question. The data structure for best performance of writing has the worst performance of reading, and vise versa. I also tried to store records of a single stations into a individual  file, which will balance the performance of reading and writing. However, the operation of `open` and netcdf file is time consumin (e.g. 0.5 s for a file, 26 min for 3100 files).

Comment: @AF7 As suggested by kakk11, compression doesn't help in my situation, as all data have to uncompress first, then  compress agai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, what You need is chunking. I created a small python script to test, without chunking it basically confirms Your observation that access is slow in one dimension. I tested with station number 3000, variables per station 10 and timesteps 10000. I did put stations and variables into the same dimension for testing, but it should give similar results in 3D case if You really need it.
My test output without chunking:

`File chunking type: None
 Variable shape: (30000, 10000)
 Total time, file creation: 13.665503025054932
 Average time for adding one measurement time:  0.00136328568459   0.00148195505142 0.0018851685524
 Read all timeseries one by one with single file open
 Average read time per station/variable:  0.524109539986`

And with chunking:

`File chunking type: [100, 100]
Variable shape: (30000, 10000)
Total time, file creation: 18.610711812973022
Average time for adding one measurement time:  0.00185681316853 0.00168470859528 0.00213300466537
Read all timeseries one by one with single file open
Average read time per station/variable:  0.000948731899261`

What You can see is that chunking increases write time by about 50%, but dramatically improves read time. I did not try to optimise chunk sizes, just tested that it works in the right direction.
Feel free to ask if code is not clear or You are not familiar with python.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from time import time
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset

test_dataset_name='test_dataset.nc4'
num_stations=3000 
num_vars=10 
chunks=None
#chunks=[100,100]

def create_dataset():
    ff=Dataset(test_dataset_name,'w')
    ff.createDimension('Time',None)
    ff.createDimension('Station_variable',num_stations*num_vars)
    if chunks:
        var1=ff.createVariable('TimeSeries','f8',   ('Station_variable','Time'),chunksizes=chunks)
    else:
        var1=ff.createVariable('TimeSeries','f8',('Station_variable','Time'))
    return ff

def add_data(ff,timedim):
    var1=ff.variables['TimeSeries']
    var1[0:1000,timedim]=timedim*np.ones((1000),'f8')

def dataset_close(inds):
    inds.close()

## CREATE DATA FILE    
time_start=time()
time1=[]
time2=[]
time3=[]
time4=[]
testds=create_dataset()
dataset_close(testds)
for i in range(10000):
    time1.append(time())
    ff=Dataset(test_dataset_name,'a')
    time2.append(time())
    add_data(ff,i)
    time3.append(time())
    ff.sync()
    ff.close()
    time4.append(time())
time_end=time()

time1=np.array(time1)
time2=np.array(time2)
time3=np.array(time3)
time4=np.array(time4)

## READ ALL STAION-VARIABLE COMBINATIONS AS ONE TIMESERIES
ff=Dataset(test_dataset_name,'r')
## PRINT DATA FILE CREATION SUMMARY
print("File chunking type:",chunks)
print("Variable shape:",ff.variables['TimeSeries'][:].shape)
print("Total time, file creation:", time_end-time_start)
print("Average time for adding one measurement time: ",np.mean(time4-    time1), np.mean(time4[:100]-time1[:100]),np.mean(time4[-100:]- time1[-100:]))
print("Read all timeseries one by one with single file open")
time_rstart=[]
time_rend=[]
for i in range(0,ff.variables['TimeSeries'][:].shape[0],int(ff.variables['TimeSeries'][:].shape[0]/100)):
    time_rstart.append(time())
    dataline=ff.variables['TimeSeries'][i,:]
    time_rend.append(time())
time_rstart=np.array(time_rstart)
time_rend=np.array(time_rend)
print("Average read time per station/variable: ",np.mean(time_rend-  time_rstart))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Chunking do working for me. I don't think I fully understand how chunking is working in nc format. Would you like to give me more explanation about it?

Comment: Glad I could help. Chunking is actually not a feature of NetCDF4 but of HDF5, which provides the underlaying tools. To put very simply, chunking is the way how data is sliced on disk: one chunk is continuous array of data and can be accessed fast. So instead of reading numbers one by one from disk, they can be read chunk by chunk. I'm not good enough expert to explain how it actually works on multi-dimensional unlimited arrays and why it does not significantly hurt writing performance. More info https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/Advanced/Chunking/